# FLUTTER Argument cant be assigned to the Parameter type

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, parameter-passing, flutter-test

**Error**: The argument type 'User (where User is defined in `<dir>\<project>\lib\pages\home.dart)'` can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User (where User is defined in `<dir>\<project>\lib\pages\timeline.dart)'.`

**Code** : home.dart

```
Scaffold buildAuthScreen() {
return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  body: PageView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Timeline(currentUser: currentUser),
      ActivityFeed(),
      Upload(currentUser: currentUser),
      Search(),
      Profile(profileId: currentUser?.id),
```

**Code** : timeline.dart

```
class Timeline extends StatefulWidget {
final User currentUser;
Timeline({this.currentUser});
```

in different pages it working but in timeline i don't why its showing this error.

[Github Link](https://github.com/OsamaxD1/SocialMediaFlutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate classes both named `User` in two different files.  Even though they have the same class name, they are different classes (even if they have identical implementations).

If they really should be separate classes, you should consider renaming them to be different.  If that's not possible, you can disambiguate them by [specifying a library prefix](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#specifying-a-library-prefix) when you import:

```
import 'timeline.dart' as timeline;
```

Then you can use `timeline.User` to refer specifically to `timeline.dart`'s version.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem. What resolved it for me was going through each file and making sure I was using the same kind of local imports (relative file listing vs package) I.E.:

```
import './local/file.dart';
import 'package:local_package/local/file.dart';
```

I also had to double check the case sensitivity on all the imports. I found through renaming and shuffling that cases were not matching to what the filesystem actually had I.E.:

```
import './local/file.dart'

Filesytem:
.../project/lib/Local/file.dart (Notice the capital L in "Local"
```

That plus a delete of the .dartServer in my home directory, a flutter clean, and just for good measure I deleted the one file that was complaining and recreated it and I was good as new.