# The argument type 'X (where User is defined in C:\PATH)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'X(where User is defined in PATH)'

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to move a dart file from one folder to another however when I do that I get this error:

> The argument type 'User (where User is defined in C:\Users\BAQ-229\AndroidStudioProjects\reviu\lib\models\user_model.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User (where User is defined in C:\Users\BAQ-229\AndroidStudioProjects\reviu\lib\models\user_model.dart)'.

I'm not sure what the problem is, the code works perfectly if I don't move it.

Comment: The error means you have two separate classes both named `User`, one defined in one `.dart` file, another defined in the other.  Rename one of them to avoid the conflict, or `import` with a prefix to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FLUTTER Argument cant be assigned to the Parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281440/flutter-argument-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type)

Comment: I don't have to separate classes named User, the only class I have is the user_model.dart that I import into different files

Comment: Okay, looking more closely at your error message, it's really weird that the path is the same in both parts of the message.  Does running `flutter clean` help?